# запретить закрывать консольную программу крестиком [си]

Tags: c, windows

Запретить закрывать консольную программу крестиком на си. ОС: Windows

Comment: есть много способов. Например, спрятать мышку или стартануть консольную программу в fullscreen. Какую именно задачу пытаетесь решить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если удалить из оконного (системного) меню команду "Close", то и кнопка "крестик" станет недоступной

```
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
HMENU hmenu = GetSystemMenu(hwnd, FALSE);
DeleteMenu(hmenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

Вместо удаления пункта меню можно его просто сделать неактивным

```
EnableMenuItem(hmenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_GRAYED);
```

Это, однако, не запретит закрытие окна по <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>.